# Use a flow typed React Component Library in both flow typed project and Typescript projects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I have run into a situation where I have some old React projects using flow, and some new projects in Typescript.

I have a component library that the team built to be used in all platforms.

Is there a way to use the flow typed react components with Typescript project?

Any links or comments will be helpful.

Comment: You'll either need to use the common subset of the two languages, which may be quite difficult depending on the code in question, where you'll need to write a separate declarations

Comment: The library already uses flow types, I guess what you mean is remove flow types and just use js without types and create definition files for flow and typescript both

Comment: I also wonder how do libraries who use types in their code are used by typescript and flow both?

Comment: Most major libraries that use Flow (React included) have independent type definitions at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types) which is community maintained.

Comment: You don't have to get rid of the flow types but rather maintain a separate set of TypeScript declaration files